# Find changes in the values of a list

Tags: python, list, arraylist

I have a list of 'random' numbers of which the first X values are either zero or very low compared to the 'important' data. I've been trying to find an efficient way to find where the jump in the values start.

For example, for a given array:
`A=[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.58, 1.96, 2.15, 1.67, 2.45]`

I want the result to be the 11th index. It doesn't really matter if the function also yield results for indexes after the 11th (in case by any chance another big jump happens between consecutive numbers), what is important is to highlight when that first jump happens.

I've been using the following code:

```
for i in range(1, len(A)):
  try:
    if A[i]>A[i-1] and A[i]-A[i-1]<=0.2 and abs(A[i]-A[i+1])>=0.2:
      print(i)
  except IndexError:
    pass
```

It gets the job done but the for loop can take a long time as the array gets bigger and bigger (im trying to use it on a matrix with over 2000 rows and 9000 columns).
I also tried with the following code

```
ok = (abs(A[:-1] - A[1:]) > 0.2)
jumps = np.where(ok == True)[0]
```

But it doesn't quite get the job done since it also highlight that jump at the 7th index. Any suggestions of what I could do?

Comment: Just use `break` after you print, it will exit the loop on the first value, and you won't be forced to process the whole list after the value you're looking for has been found

Comment: you can also put `for`-loop in function and use `return`  to exit function when you find first matching element.

Comment: if you want to use `A[i+1]` then you could use range()` with `len(A)-1` and you will no need `try/except`.

Comment: Code `if A[i]>A[i-1] and A[i]-A[i-1]<=0.2 and ...` you can write as `if A[i]-A[i-1]>0 and A[i]-A[i-1]<=0.2 and ...` and this you can write as more readble `if 0 < A[i] - A[i-1] <= 0.2 and ...`

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could do the following, if you have some cutoff value `c` which you define as ‘very low’:

```py
next(i for i,v in enumerate(A) if v > c)
```